# Context for GraphQl resolvers undefined

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm new to graphQL but for whatever reason is seems like my context parameter is undefined in my resolver. Here is how I am setting up the server:

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileLoader, mergeTypes, mergeResolvers } from 'merge-graphql-schemas';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import models from './models';

const typeDefs = mergeTypes(fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, './schema')));

const resolvers = mergeResolvers(fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, './resolvers')));

const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
   typeDefs, 
   resolvers,
  });

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

models.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(x => {
  app.listen({ port: PORT }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
  );
});
```

Example Resolver:

```
export default {
  Query: {
    getUser: (parent, { id }, { models }) => models.User.findOne({ where: { id } }),
    allUsers: (parent, args, { models }) => models.User.findAll(),
  },
  Mutation: {
    createUser: (parent, args, { models }) => models.User.create(args),
  },
};
```

When I try to do the createUser mutation I get the error: Cannot read property 'User' of undefined.

Which means my context object parameter is undefined. Any help is appreciated, GraphQL setup has been a bit confusing for me.

Comment: because no context defs ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: models not passed into context

Comment: can i just pass it in as a 2nd parameter to the constructor of ApolloServer? Can you link me to docs where this is done cant seem to find it

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#the-context-argument - fn returning object or simply object with `models` prop `context: { models }`

Comment: Ahhhh thanks... my issue was I didn't wrap my models in an object thanks..